# Python | TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int' |use Variable to divide

Tags: python, math

```
a = int(float(input("Add : ")))
b =  int(float(input("Add : ")))
c = print(" = " , a**2 + b**2)

print(c/2)
```

I'm going to divide the variable and the number but it happens like this, how do I fix it?
| TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Don't use `int(float(input("x")))`.  Just use `int(input("x"))`.  Going from string to float to int serves no purpose.  Just go directly from string to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` returns `None`, which you assign to `c`. `None` can't be divided by an `int`, hence your error.

If you want to store the result of `a**2 + b**2` in `c`, then do so directly:

```py
a = int(input("Add: "))
b = int(input("Add: "))
c = a**2 + b**2

print(f"{a=}, {b=}, {c=}")
print(c / 2)
```

Sample execution:

```
Add: 3
Add: 5
a=3, b=5, c=34
17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a function which returns `None` and the side effect of printing its args to `stdout`.
Therefore c has the value `None`. And `None / 2` gives the `TypeError`